# Why does modifying a list inside a tuple using the "+=" operator in Python result in a changed list, despite tuples being immutable?

Tags: python, tuples

We all know that a tuple in Python is an immutable object which means we can’t change the elements once it is created.

```
my_tuple = ([1],[2],[3])
my_tuple[2] = [3,4,5]
```

Output:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

However when I do:

```
my_tuple[2] += [4,5]:
```

I get the same error:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

but the interesting part is when I print the value of `my_tuple`:

```
print(my_tuple)
```

I get:

```
([1], [2], [3, 4, 5])
```

so my question is why does modifying a list inside a tuple using the `+=` operator in Python result in a changed list, despite tuples being immutable?

Comment: The tuple _itself_ is immutable (meaning elements cannot be added, removed, nor reassigned).  The _elements_ of a tuple may be mutated (assuming they are a mutable type).  For lists, the `+=` operator is _mutation_, not _assignment_.

Comment: Could someone voting for reopen explain how the linked duplicate _isn't_ precisely on-point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `+=` operator modifies in-place.

So, modifying list in-place is **good**. Then assigns the value back to tuple which is **bad** (it throws error).

Since the first operation is successful, it modifies the list then throws error.

> These methods are called to implement the augmented arithmetic assignments `(+=, -=, *=, @=, /=, //=, %=, **=, <<=, >>=, &=, ^=, |=)`. These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self).

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types